# Replace double quotes with brackets in nested HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I am trying to create a script to replace all my double quote texts to be insert inside brackets.

> Eg:
> Input : This "is" a "text".
> Output : This [is] a [text].

I have tried to fetch all the text elements and using regex replace and print the bracekts.

**But it is not working as expected for nested elements.**

This is my code sample

**HTML**

```
 <p>this "is" a "text" 
   <small>this is "small" text</small>
 </p>
 <h1>"this" is "another"</h1>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, div, span, small, b, strong, li').each(function(){

                var re = /([^"]*"[^"]*)"/gm; 
                var str = $(this).text();
                var subst = '$1»'; 
                var result = str.replace(re, subst);
                var resultOdd = result.replace(/"/g, '«');
                $(this).text(resultOdd);
            
        });


        

    })
```

[This is the fiddle for the same.](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/387sxnce/)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "[$1]");`

Comment: In question heading you asked about replacing angle brackets, in example you have shown square brackes. What exact replacement you are looking for?

Comment: do you need escapings? could this happenen : "text text\" excaped teext\" text"? If yes, it would be apain to do it with regex, better use other tools

Comment: The regex is only part of the problem. Your much bigger issue is working with text Nodes and recursively looping through nested elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Exactly... The above code will not work properly for nested elements.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.